# Band selection circuit for SI4825 A10

Tags: resistors, radio, diy, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

Following the official schematic and guideline (AN738: Si4825/36-A
Antenna, Schematic, Layout, and Design Guidelines), I am building a [Si825 A10](https://www.skyworksinc.com/en/Products/Audio-and-Radio/Si4825-31-35-36-Mechanically-Tuned-AM-FM-Radio-Receivers/Si4825-A20-CS)-based radio receiver.

I am getting weak audio output even with an audio amplifier, but band selection and tuning are still not working.
I am using a 470 kΩ pot and spare resistance for band selection, as I do not have access to the exact value for the resistance.

Is it possible to achieve band selection using the above parts?

[image: Schematic for band selection]

Comment: refer to the document that is mentioned in the datasheet section `4.6. Band Select`

Comment: Have referred to the guideline, not very clear to me as I am new to electronics.

Comment: With pins 10 and 11 grounded then you use the volume control on the audio amplifier to control loudness.

Answer (score 0):

Since band selection is not working, have you verified both your connections for TUNE1 and BAND? In the schematic the TUNE1 connection is shown using ***logical connectivity*** with labels instead of showing a physical line. Easy to read, but if you are new it is even easier to overlook.

The weak audio output could be a lot of things. Fix the band selection and then check your grounds.

[image]